# NSPredicate for fetching items from to-many relationship excluding particular related entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have a core date setup as:

```
Item-
id: String
name: String
projects: [Project]? (many-to-many optional relationship)

Project-
id: String
name: String
items: [Item]? (many-to-many optional relationship)
```

When I want to fetch all items from particular project, I use this predicate:
`NSPredicate(format: "ANY projects.id == %@", project.id)`

Now, I've to fetch all the items those don't have relationship with particular project.
To do that I'm trying using below predicate:
`NSPredicate(format: "(projects.@count == 0) OR (NONE projects.id == %@)", project.id)`

The problem with this predicate is that it doesn't work correctly with items which are related to more than one project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using SUBQUERY instead of the ANY, ALL, NONE operators that Apple provides (NONE in particular is one to avoid).

```
NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(projects, $p, $p.id == %@).@count == 0", project.id)
```